# Trying to mock HttpContext giving me type issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, httpcontext

So I need to write a unit test for a method in a asp.net mvc controller. I almost have the unit test done, the only problem now is that the method I want to test contains something that looks like this:

```
GetSessionState(this.session, stateKey);
```

so, I need to have something that can create at mocked session for me.
I have before used the mock library to create dummy objects.
I have attempted to simulate a session like this, in my unit test method

```
Mock<HttpContext> mockedHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
HttpContext.Current = mockedHttpContext.Object;
```

When I compile, this looks fine, but when run the test, I get the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class. '

I have then tried to use a interface like this:

```
IMock<HttpContext> mockedHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
HttpContext.Current = mockedHttpContext.Object;
```

or this:

```
var mockedHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
HttpContext.Current = mockedHttpContext.Object;
```

But no luck here either, does someone know what i need to do? do i need to fill out the values of the session maybe?

Comment: Which version of asp.net do you use?

Comment: version 4.8  and is using sitecore

Comment: Any luck on how to mock HTTPContext ?